# Python mouse event

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to activate a function in python which will save a timestamp to a file. However, I wish to activate that function after the first mouse click that accurses outside the Tk window. 
For example, after running the program I will minimize it and press on the chrome browser icon and while doing so my program will log the time stamp.

I tried to use the bind function but it works for clicks that accrue only in the Tk window

By the way, I am currently using Tkinter as my GUI platform however if there is a way to do it with another libraries please share and I will adjust my program

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<FocusOut>` event:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def focus_lost(event):
    print("Clicked outside the window")

root.bind("<FocusOut>", focus_lost)

root.mainloop()
```

If you are focussed on the tkinter window (e.g. if you have clicked on it), then when you click elsewhere it will detect this as a `<FocusOut>` event.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for , Is there any way to limit this to the first click and that's it?

Comment: Thank you a lot, I used the unbind option after the first click . 
Was looking for your answer for hours now